# ¿Es común omitir 'de' cuando se habla de funciones de un variable o de una expresión?

Tags: matemáticas

En inglés, cuando se ve 'sin(x)', es propio decir 'sine of x', pero también es comun decir 'sine x'.  Es decir, omitir la palabra 'of' es común cuando se habla de funciones de un variable.  También es común cuando es una función de una expresión.  Por ejemplo:  'sin(x^2)' se puede decir 'sine x^2' sin la palabra 'of'.

¿Es común hacer lo mismo en español?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Según mi experiencia (ingeniero, argentino), no, no es común la omisión. Casi siempre se dice "seno de x", y lo mismo en expresiones análogas.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy de acuerdo en que no se acostumbra, y de hecho, hacerlo sonaría muy raro y sería la primera vez que lo escuchase decir de esa manera. Es preferible decir "seno de x", suena más propio. Además, recuerda que no siempre las mismas reglas en inglés pueden ser aplicadas al español.

Answer (score 2):

Al contrario de lo que dicen otras respuestas, cuando estudiaba ingeniería en la universidad (en España), yo sí oí decir "seno equis cuadrado" en lugar de "seno de equis al cuadrado" y cosas similares bastante a menudo.

Obviamente, no es la forma "correcta", ni formal, pero cuando alguien está leyendo fórmulas en voz alta todo el rato, a menudo las abrevia, especialmente si están escritas al lado.